# Run linear regression fit on 2 1D array

Tags: linear-regression

On doing this-

```
x = np.random.rand(200)
.
.

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size =0.20, random_state = 0)
    reg = LinearRegression()
    reg.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

I got the following error 
[image]

Although I do understand that I am not passing the parameters properly. But not 
sure how to make it into a  2D array for linear regression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `np.reshape` you can transform your input `x` to Scikit's necessary input shape

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size =0.20, random_state = 0)
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1,1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1,1)
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x_train,y_train)
```